# "moment is not defined" error using FullCalendar with Laravel Mix workflow

Tags: javascript, webpack, fullcalendar, momentjs, laravel-mix

I'm working at a custom WordPress theme that includes **FullCalendar** (and its dependency **MomentJs**). I'm using **Laravel Mix** to 'compile' the assets and javascript modules. Calling the function `moment()` in a module, after having imported FullCalendar module, generates error

> 'Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined at
>   MonthView.viewRender'... etc

I've tried to explicitly import Moment module (before FullCalendar one) with no change. The only thing that works is adding explicitly moment.js as standalone file included in the page (without 'compiling' it in app.js). Latest versions of FullCalendar and MomentJS.
Obviously run: `npm install moment fullcalendar`

**app.js** (fragment)

```
import 'moment';
import 'fullcalendar';

import Calendar from './modules/calendar.js';
```

**calendar.js** (fragment)

```
const calendar0 = $(".c-calendar--0");

calendar0.fullCalendar({
    locale: 'it',
    header: {
        left: 'title',
        center: '',
        right: 'prev,next today'
    },
    defaultDate: '2019-02-01',
    events: all_events,
    viewRender: function (view, element) {
        let cur = view.intervalStart;
        let d = moment(cur).add('months', 1);
        calendar1.fullCalendar('gotoDate', d);
    }
});
```

I'd like to be able to use Moment's functions in the calendar module without errors, bundling the code with Laravel Mix.

Comment: try importing those files from calendar.js

Comment: Still the same error even with the imports at the top of calendar.js module

Comment: In your calendar.js file change `import moment` to `import moment from "moment"`

I assume you have installed moment with npm